# Flutter http exception

Tags: authentication, flutter, exception, dart

So while following some tutorials, I get into this weird exception which keeps on coming and freezing my app.

This exception comes when i throw the exception:
[image: Exception in VS CODE]

Here is the handling screen of my exception.

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;
  DateTime _expiryDate;
  String _userId;

  Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url =
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:$urlSegment?key=YOUR_API_KEY';
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responseData);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        print("FUCK");
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
    } on HttpException catch (error) {
      print(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signUp(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signUp');
  }

  Future<void> logIn(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signInWithPassword');
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would understand why it would pause the application during debug build as the debugger kicks in, but do you mean it freezes the app in release mode?
BTW, you can use just `rethrow;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you throw error?
if you don't handle it that in other places of your app it can freeze or even crash application.
You should handle this exception instead of re-throw or put execution of this method in try catch and handle exception in catch bloc.

As I said you have 2 options:

1. remove `throw error`
2. put execution to another `try catch` and
   `handle`(not thrown) it appropriately(normally just log exception for further investigation)

Comment: I am handling it another screen, but the problem is when exception is arising when i throw the error. The exception is not thrown to screen where i am handling it . I have attached image of the error handling.

Comment: Could you please show last catch block? Seems your rethrown error goes here but we need full example to understand the reason